# Automatically cache EFS data on Fargate ephemeral storage

Tags: aws-fargate, amazon-efs

Is there a way to cache the data that my Fargate tasks read from EFS on the ephemeral storage to which the Fargate task has access in a way that is transparent to my application ?

The goal is to improve the performance when my application has to read the same file multiple times during the lifetime of the Fargate task:

- The first time the file is read from EFS (which is relatively slow compared to reading from ephemeral storage)
- A second, third, ... read would read the cached version from ephemeral storage

If I was using a regular EC2 machine, I would probably use something like [cachefilesd](https://linux.die.net/man/8/cachefilesd) as described [here](https://superuser.com/a/446711), but that requires control over how the EFS volume is mounted. And AFAIK I have no control over that in Fargate.

I'm creating the Fargate tasks using Cloudformation, so a solution that is supported by Cloudformation would be best.

In case it is relevant:

- the Fargate tasks where I want to use this only read from EFS, but never write to it (for now).
- I'm not using EKS, just ECS

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't think it's possible. It would be extremely nice to have though.